# Issues with arithmetic-operators

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

my problem is that I'm trying to put a simple math formula in a PowerShell script but this "arithmetic-operators" is an issue now for me, It was used to work this way, but something changed and now doesn't matter what I put in it multiples for more numbers as if they were letters, (it's only stacking all of them together)

I even tried fixing it using

`$x=[int]$xx`

to fix my variables so PowerShell could understand, and it did work just not with broken numbers `Ex: 7.5 or 3.1 or 9.6` No broken numbers. Can anyone help me

```
$pi=[math]::pi
$xx= Read-Host -prompt "X "
$yy= Read-Host -prompt "Y "
$zz= Read-Host -prompt "Z "
$x=[int]$xx
$y=[int]$yy
$z=[int]$zz
$re = $z * $y
$r = $z * $x + $y * $x + $z * $x + $y * $x
$res = 2 * ($re) + $r
echo .
echo "$r = $z * $x + $y * $x + $z * $x + $y * $x"
echo .
echo "$re = $z * $y"
echo .
echo "$res = 2 * ($re) + $r"
echo .
echo "Total = $res"
echo .
pause
```

if you run this and put X as 27, Y as 7.5 and Z as 17, your answer should be 1578, and you fixed it

Comment: You are getting the wrong answer because 7.5 is not an `[int]`. It is rounding 7.5 to 8 to cast it to an int. You need `$y=[single]$yy` to make this work or any other type that supports decimals. I would replace all `[int]` with `[single]` if expect decimal values.

Comment: @AdminOfThings that would be great as an answer!

Answer (score 4):

You are getting the wrong answer because 7.5 is not an `[int]`. It is rounding 7.5 to 8 to cast it to an int. You need `$y=[single]$yy` to make this work or any other type that supports decimals. I would replace all `[int]` with `[single]` if expect decimal values. See the following:

```
$pi=[math]::pi
$xx= Read-Host -prompt "X "
$yy= Read-Host -prompt "Y "
$zz= Read-Host -prompt "Z "
$x=[single]$xx
$y=[single]$yy
$z=[single]$zz
$re = $z * $y
$r = $z * $x + $y * $x + $z * $x + $y * $x
$res = 2 * ($re) + $r
echo "$r = $z * $x + $y * $x + $z * $x + $y * $x"
echo "$re = $z * $y"
echo "$res = 2 * ($re) + $r"
echo "Total = $res"
```

**Output of the variables above:**

```
$x,$y,$z,$re,$r,$res
27
7.5
17
127.5
1323
1578
```

Other types that you could potentially use are `[double]`, which is the default type of uncasted numbers with decimals, and `[decimal]`. You can also use the `-as` type operator like `$y = $yy -as [double]`. See [About Type Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_type_operators?view=powershell-6)